# Durandal widget needs a mobile view, can I use two views for one viewmodel?

Tags: mvvm, durandal, durandal-2.0

I have a Durandal widget, but now a mobile view is needed, this new view would use the same viewmodel. Would something like the following work:

```
if(mobile)
  widget.mapKind('myWidget','widgets/myWidget/mobileview','widgets/myWidget/viewmodel')
else //map with other view
```

and having a folder layout like:

```
widgets
|
|--myWidget
|--|--viewmodel
|--|--desktopview
|--|--mobileview
```

is this even good practice or should viewmodels only have one view?

If so is there another way to do this without having a different myWidgetMobile widget that duplicates a whole viewmodel?

I want to have the phone version as independent from the other view as possible so taking a mobile first approach with css is viewed as my plan Z.

Comment: Yeah, without going into the implementation, that's  exactly how it should be.. in a well designed app using MVVM pattern, you should be able to use the same ViewModel with different Views....

Comment: @Monty Thank you, I was fairly sure this approach would work, I was more worried about using bad MVVM practices, as I'm fairly new to it.